# How to clone an image multiple times on page load in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying hard to solve this problem, but unsuccessful so far..
I am a beginner in javascript with little understanding, so any help should be greatly appreciated.
Basically, I have one image that I would like to display multiple times on page load, but using a random number between 15 and 30. So, if the random number is 15, I would like to clone the image 15 times on page load.
I am not sure whether it is clear or not, but let us say I use this function to find the random number: Math.floor(Math.random()*16)+15;
But, I do not know how to link this random number to my image so that it is displayed on page load.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var toDup = document.querySelector('.to-duplicate');
console.log(toDup);
var numDuplicates = Math.floor(Math.random()*16)+15;
for (var dup = 0; dup < numDuplicates; dup++) {
    toDup.parentNode.appendChild(toDup.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<img class="to-duplicate" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is finally what I did as I kept trying after posting my question:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            var nb = Math.floor(Math.random()*16)+15;
            var theBoard = document.getElementById("board");
                        
            function generateNumbers(){
                for(i = 0; i < nb; i++){
                    var flames = document.createElement("img");
                    flames.setAttribute("src", "img/allumette.png");
                    flames.setAttribute("alt", "flamme");
                    theBoard.appendChild(flames);
                } 
            }
        
        </script>